# Crystals tag: keep it?

Tags: discussion, tags

A new tag has just been created: [crystals](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystals).

Shall we keep it? What is this tag about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it much, tags that are only associated with one question are [automatically deleted after 6 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/350545). I suggest just wait and see if there are other people that find value from it.